# What is wrong? I can't findout the error

Tags: verilog

```
module task_test;

reg[7:0] opd1;
reg[3:0] opd2;

initial begin
  opd1 = 3; opd2 = 5;
  add_shift_multiply(opd1, opd2);
  $display("%d: %d", $time, opd1);

  #10 opd1 = 6; opd2 = 7;
  add_shift_multiply(opd1, opd2);
  $display("%d: %d", $time, opd1);

  #10 $stop;
end

task add_shift_multiply(inout[7:0] a, input[3:0] b);
  reg[7:0] prod;
  reg[3:0] multiplicand;
  begin
    prod = 8'h00; multiplicand = a[3:0];
    repeat(4) begin
      if(b[0])
        prod = prod + {multiplicand, 4'h0};
        b = b + 1;
        prod = prod + 1;
    end
    a = prod;
  end
endtask

endmodule
```

When I debug this code using synapticad tool, the result is error. But I can't find out what's in this code.

Comment: Whats the error? And why the slashes?

Comment: Refer to faq's on how to use this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

[EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Tx8) looks fine as it outputs:

```
Chronologic VCS simulator copyright 1991-2014
Contains Synopsys proprietary information.
Compiler version J-2014.12-SP1-1; Runtime version J-2014.12-SP1-1;  Feb 25 16:24 2016
                   0: 100
                  10: 196
```

NB: Do you mean to do :

```
repeat(4) begin
  if(b[0]) begin
    prod = prod + {multiplicand, 4'h0};
    b = b + 1;
    prod = prod + 1;
  end
end
```

Or (as this is what you have in code) :

```
repeat(4) begin
  if(b[0]) begin
    prod = prod + {multiplicand, 4'h0};
  end
  b = b + 1;
  prod = prod + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the radix of the numbers i.e 8'd3 in the case of the assignment to opd1